# Sum of row and column in SQL pivot table

Tags: c#, sql, pivot

```
price   c_melli cost_teacher
150000  5099572650  1         
170000  5099572650  1         
170000  5099572650  1         
150000  0015601218  1         
170000  0015601218  1         
200000  0015601218  1         
200000  0015601218  2         
200000  0015601218  2         
200000  0015601218  1   

select * from
(select * from temp) as s 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(price)
    FOR [cost_teacher] IN ([1],[2],[3])
) as p1
```

result is:

```
c_melli            1     2   3
0015601218  720000  400000  NULL
5099572650  490000  NULL    NULL
```

I want to add column with count of 1 and 2 and 3
and add column with sum of each row
and add a row to end for calculate each columns.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select t.c_melli, s.[1], c.[1], s.[2], c.[2], s[3], c.[3], s.[1]+s.[2]+s.[3] as sumRow from (select distinct c_Melli from temp) t
inner join(
  select * from
  (select * from temp) as s 
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM(price)
    FOR [cost_teacher] IN ([1],[2],[3])
  ) as p1
) s on s.mellicode = t.mellicode
inner join(
  select * from
  (select * from temp) as s 
  PIVOT
  (
    Count(price)
    FOR [cost_teacher] IN ([1],[2],[3])
  ) as p1
) c on c.mellicode = t.mellicode
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually advise that people do their summary lines in the reporting tool or web page or wherever the data is going.  It's too easy to get the total line mixed in with the detail lines if the record order isn't rigidly defined.

But what you want is possible, and here's a way to do it:

```
;
-- Turning the original query into a CTE allows us to easily re-use it in the query
with detail as (
  select c_melli
     ,   [1]
     ,   [2]
     ,   [3]      
  from
  (select * from temp) as s 
    PIVOT
   (
      SUM(price)
      FOR [cost_teacher] IN ([1],[2],[3])
   ) as p1
)
-- The first SELECT retrieves the detail pivoted row, plus a calculated total of all columns.
select  c_melli
   ,    [1]
   ,    [2]
   ,    [3]
   ,    row_total = COALESCE([1],0) + COALESCE([2],0) + COALESCE([3],0)
from  detail
-- using "union all" rather than "union" because "union all" skips the
-- duplicate-removal step (which we don't need) and is therefore faster.
union all 
-- The section SELECT summarizes all of the detail rows.  
select 'total'  -- this assumes c_melli is a string; if not, use something else
  ,     SUM([1])
  ,     SUM([2])
  ,     SUM([3])
  ,     SUM(COALESCE([1],0) + COALESCE([2],0) + COALESCE([3],0))
from    detail
```

Disclaimer:  I did this from memory and have not tested it.

Comment: and solution for getting cost_teacher column dynamically and count of each one???????

Comment: @user3527426  Oops, I misread your question and thought you wanted sums rather than counts of records.  But I see someone else was able to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using WITH ROLLUP?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING(c_melli) = 1) THEN 'Total'
        ELSE ISNULL(c_melli, 'UNKNOWN')
   END as c_melli, 
   [1], [2], [3], [1]+[2]+[3] as Total 
FROM
  (select * from temp) as s 
PIVOT
(
  SUM(price)
  FOR [cost_teacher] IN ([1],[2],[3])
) as p1
GROUP BY c_melli WITH ROLLUP
```